# C++ program not decrementing correctly

Tags: c++, loops, random

So, I am making a program where you can add marbles to a bag. You choose the color you want, then the number of marbles you want to add, and then if that color marble is either cool, boring, or weird. So if you want to add 10 blue marbles, and then you chose cool. You will have ten total marbles and ten marbles that are blue and cool. I go to remove a random marble from the marbles that are stored already after I add. For some reason, it isn't working at all. I attempt to get a random number and assign that random number to a description of a current marble that has already been added. Say if the random number generated is 1 it will remove a "red cool marble". I obviously can't remove a marble that hasn't been added so I added a `do - while` loop, which basically loops back through the random number generator until it finds a number that satisfies the criteria. Here is my code, any thoughts? :

I tried changing the position of my Do while loop.

```
  void remove() {


do {
srand(time(0));


randomnum = (rand () % max) +1 ;





if (randomnum == 1 && redcool > 0)  {

  red--;
  redcool--;
  cout << "The random marble removed was a red and cool marble" <<endl;
}
else if (randomnum == 2 && redweird > 0) {
cout << "The random marble removed was a red and weirdl marble" <<endl;
  red--;
  redweird--;
}
else if (randomnum == 3 && redboring > 0) {
cout << "The random marble removed was a red and boring marble" <<endl;
  red--;
  redboring--;
}
else if (randomnum == 4 && greencool > 0) {
cout << "The random marble removed was a green and cool marble" <<endl;
  green--;
  greencool--;
}
else if (randomnum == 5 && greenweird > 0) {
cout << "The random marble removed was a green and weird marble" <<endl;
  green--;
  greenweird--;

}
else if (randomnum == 6 && greenboring > 0) {
cout << "The random marble removed was a green and boring marble" <<endl;
  greenboring--;
  green--;
}
else if (randomnum == 7 && bluecool > 0) {
  cout << "The random marble removed was a green and cool marble" <<endl;
  blue--;
  bluecool--;

}
else if (randomnum == 8 && blueboring >0) {
cout << "The random marble removed was a blue and cool marble" <<endl;
  blue--;
  blueboring--;

}
else if (randomnum == 9 && blueweird > 0) {
cout << "The random marble removed was a blue and weird marble" <<endl;
  blue--;
  blueweird--;
}


}while (randomnum == 1 && redcool > 0 || randomnum == 2 && redweird >0 || randomnum == 3
&& redboring > 0 || randomnum == 4 && greencool > 0 || randomnum == 5 && greenweird >0 || randomnum == 6
&& greenboring > 0 || randomnum == 7 && bluecool > 0 || randomnum == 8 && blueweird >0 || randomnum == 9
&& blueboring > 0);



bag--;
```

The expected result would say I added ten marbles that are blue and cool. When I go to remove a random marble it will then decrement a blue and cool marble because that is the only value that is in the bag. Currently, nothing is even being removed.

Comment: that `while` condition is doomed to fail

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks for replying my man! fixed the changes, and still not getting anything to decrement.

Comment: @o_weisman oops looks like I messed up and programmed my assignment in java!

Comment: @EricPostpischil I just edited my original post to the code I have now! Thanks again Mate

Comment: Putting `srand` inside the loop causes `rand` to generate the same number every time until at least one second has passed. In consequence, it may be many seconds before it happens upon the number for the “blue and cool” case. `srand` should be called only once when starting a sequence of random numbers (often just once at the beginning of a program).

Comment: Additionally, you may want to change the code so that it terminates when a category changes from non-empty to empty. Currently, the code terminates when a category selected by the random number generation is already empty or becomes empty.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the original question was flawed by having a superfluous case for `randomnum == 7`. The edited code is flawed by having `srand` inside the loop.

Sample working code with minimal changes from the original is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


void remove(void)
{
    int max = 9;
    int randomnum;

    int redcool = 2;
    int redweird = 2;
    int redboring = 2;
    int red = redcool + redweird + redboring;
    int greencool = 2;
    int greenweird = 2;
    int greenboring = 2;
    int green = greencool + greenweird + greenboring;
    int bluecool = 2;
    int blueweird = 2;
    int blueboring = 2;
    int blue = bluecool + blueweird + blueboring;
    int bag = red+green+blue;

    srand(time(0));

    do
    {
        randomnum = (rand() % max) + 1;

        if (randomnum == 1 && redcool > 0)
        {
            red--;
            redcool--;
            cout << "The random marble removed was a red and cool marble" << endl;
        }
        else if (randomnum == 2 && redweird > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a red and weird marble" << endl;
            red--;
            redweird--;
        }
        else if (randomnum == 3 && redboring > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a red and boring marble" << endl;
            red--;
            redboring--;
        }
        else if (randomnum == 4 && greencool > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a green and cool marble" << endl;
            green--;
            greencool--;
        }
        else if (randomnum == 5 && greenweird > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a green and weird marble" << endl;
            green--;
            greenweird--;

        }
        else if (randomnum == 6 && greenboring > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a green and boring marble" << endl;
            greenboring--;
            green--;
        }
        else if (randomnum == 7 && bluecool > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a blue and cool marble" << endl;
            blue--;
            bluecool--;

        }
        else if (randomnum == 8 && blueweird > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a blue and weird marble" << endl;
            blue--;
            blueweird--;
        }
        else if (randomnum == 9 && blueboring > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a blue and boring marble" << endl;
            blue--;
            blueboring--;
        }

    } while (
        randomnum == 1 && redcool > 0 ||
        randomnum == 2 && redweird > 0 ||
        randomnum == 3 && redboring > 0 ||
        randomnum == 4 && greencool > 0 ||
        randomnum == 5 && greenweird > 0 ||
        randomnum == 6 && greenboring > 0 ||
        randomnum == 7 && bluecool > 0 ||
        randomnum == 8 && blueweird > 0 ||
        randomnum == 9 && blueboring > 0);

    bag--;

    std::cout << "redcool = " << redcool << ".\n";
    std::cout << "redweird = " << redweird << ".\n";
    std::cout << "redboring = " << redboring << ".\n";
    std::cout << "red = " << red << ".\n";
    std::cout << "greencool = " << greencool << ".\n";
    std::cout << "greenweird = " << greenweird << ".\n";
    std::cout << "greenboring = " << greenboring << ".\n";
    std::cout << "green = " << green << ".\n";
    std::cout << "bluecool = " << bluecool << ".\n";
    std::cout << "blueweird = " << blueweird << ".\n";
    std::cout << "blueboring = " << blueboring << ".\n";
    std::cout << "blue = " << blue << ".\n";
    std::cout << "bag = " << bag << ".\n";
}


int main(void)
{
    remove();
}
```

Note that, when any category starts empty, this code will stop as soon as it is selected by the random number generation. If it is desired to stop only when a category transitions from not-empty to empty, changes must be made. One way to do this is to use another variable to indicate whether or not such a transition has been seen. In the code below, a variable called `trigger` is set to one when a just-changed counter has become zero:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


void remove(void)
{
    int max = 9;
    int randomnum;

    int redcool = 0;
    int redweird = 0;
    int redboring = 0;
    int red = redcool + redweird + redboring;
    int greencool = 0;
    int greenweird = 0;
    int greenboring = 0;
    int green = greencool + greenweird + greenboring;
    int bluecool = 10;
    int blueweird = 0;
    int blueboring = 0;
    int blue = bluecool + blueweird + blueboring;
    int bag = red+green+blue;

    srand(time(0));

    int trigger = 0;
    do
    {
        randomnum = (rand() % max) + 1;

        if (randomnum == 1 && redcool > 0)
        {
            red--;
            redcool--;
            trigger = redcool == 0;
            cout << "The random marble removed was a red and cool marble" << endl;
        }
        else if (randomnum == 2 && redweird > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a red and weird marble" << endl;
            red--;
            redweird--;
            trigger = redweird == 0;
        }
        else if (randomnum == 3 && redboring > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a red and boring marble" << endl;
            red--;
            redboring--;
            trigger = redboring == 0;
        }
        else if (randomnum == 4 && greencool > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a green and cool marble" << endl;
            green--;
            greencool--;
            trigger = greencool == 0;
        }
        else if (randomnum == 5 && greenweird > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a green and weird marble" << endl;
            green--;
            greenweird--;
            trigger = greenweird == 0;

        }
        else if (randomnum == 6 && greenboring > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a green and boring marble" << endl;
            greenboring--;
            green--;
            trigger = greenboring == 0;
        }
        else if (randomnum == 7 && bluecool > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a blue and cool marble" << endl;
            blue--;
            bluecool--;
            trigger = bluecool == 0;

        }
        else if (randomnum == 8 && blueweird > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a blue and weird marble" << endl;
            blue--;
            blueweird--;
            trigger = blueweird == 0;
        }
        else if (randomnum == 9 && blueboring > 0)
        {
            cout << "The random marble removed was a blue and boring marble" << endl;
            blue--;
            blueboring--;
            trigger = blueboring == 0;
        }

    } while (!trigger);

    bag--;

    std::cout << "redcool = " << redcool << ".\n";
    std::cout << "redweird = " << redweird << ".\n";
    std::cout << "redboring = " << redboring << ".\n";
    std::cout << "red = " << red << ".\n";
    std::cout << "greencool = " << greencool << ".\n";
    std::cout << "greenweird = " << greenweird << ".\n";
    std::cout << "greenboring = " << greenboring << ".\n";
    std::cout << "green = " << green << ".\n";
    std::cout << "bluecool = " << bluecool << ".\n";
    std::cout << "blueweird = " << blueweird << ".\n";
    std::cout << "blueboring = " << blueboring << ".\n";
    std::cout << "blue = " << blue << ".\n";
    std::cout << "bag = " << bag << ".\n";
}


int main(void)
{
    remove();
}
```